# Solr custom ranking

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, sphinx

Using Sphinx I can rank document any way I want.

```
SELECT *
FROM someIndex
WHERE MATCH('foo bar')
OPTION ranker=expr('<any rank expression>')
```

How can I achieve same behavior with Solr? Is `{!boost q=<some_boost_expression>}` is the only way? For example, I need to documents with more number of words have higher score:

```
A: foo bar blah blah blah
B: foo bar
```

I need A to be more relevant for `foo bar` query. Right now B have higher score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply boost functions (bf attribute) to customize your scoring in a more complex way than a simple query term boost.  This is available in the [DisMax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29), and, as you might expect, is further extended in the [Extended dismax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#bf_.28Boost_Function.2C_additive.29)

The [norm](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#norm) is where you would normally expect to find information readily available about the length of the field, although it will be combined with any field level boost found, and you logic (to weigh more heavily the longer field) is the reverse of the default scoring.  That will make supporting field boosts and that logic difficult, unless you create a custom Similarity.  Norms, by the way, are stored at index time, not calculated at query time, if you decide to take that route.